# How to get href from a parent class?

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

I am trying to get all the href links from a parent class which is like this:

```
<div class="parentClass">
   <article class="className">
      <a href="link1">
      </a>
   </article>
   <article class="className">
      <a href="link2">
      </a>
   </article>
</div>
```

What is the correct way to locate the href element?

Answer (score 3):

Use below xpath

```
//div[@class='parentClass']//*[@href]
```

Use code as below:

```
  List<WebElement> list=driver.findElements(By.xpath("//div[@class='parentClass']//*[@href]"));

   for(WebElement e : list){
       String link = e.getAttribute("href");
       System.out.println(e.getTagName() + "=" + link);
   }
```

Comment: Might want to do a `[contains(@class, 'parentClass')]` in case the element has one more class name.

Answer (score 1):

If you use below xpath then you will locate all href elements from the parent

```
//div[@class="parentClass"]//article[*]//a[*]
```

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to do this is to use a CSS selector, `div.parentClass a`. I would suggest that you also add a wait because the page may take a few seconds to load, depending on how much data it contains. After that, you just need to locate all matching elements, loop through each one and get the `href` attribute, and print them (or whatever else you want to do with them). The code with these suggestions is below.

```
List<WebElement> links = new WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfAllElementsLocatedBy(By.cssSelector("div.parentClass a")));
for (WebElement webElement : links)
{
    System.out.println(webElement.getAttribute("href"));
}
```